# SQL development tools not avaliable on Spring tool suite in eclipse market

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, eclipse-plugin

I cant find " SQL development tools " in eclipse market does any one know the solution ?

I just started learning java, so I can be a beginner in most subjects. I couldn't find what I wanted in the eclipse store. A few people asked a question about it 1 year ago, but since I couldn't find a specific answer, I wanted to open this topic again. At the same time, I'm trying to learn java by following a video series. I would be very happy if you can help.

Comment: Spring boot comes with h2, which has a perfectly good web console. Not sure what more you would need.

Comment: aha thank you for this answer can you rep+ for me